# Error When Enabling Contact as Customer

Tags: community, customer-community, community-cloud

We are getting below red error when enabling contact as a customer from the contact record page.
We tried everything, creating a new record type, assigning target profile access to record type, Converting account as a partner, etc.

The community (Experience) site is already active. and target profile is assigned to the members of the community.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't create Community users from Setup > Manage Users.  Instead, you have to go to the Contact record and click the Manage External Users button.  If you don't see the button, you need to add a set of buttons to the page layout - Enable Customer User, View Customer User, etc.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I did mention that I'm enabling a contact as a community user. This page appears when you click on Enable As Customer User, It navigates to user creation page.